Is the contravariant power set functor more "natural" than the covariant power set functor?
There are two natural ways to make the power set operation into a functor $\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$: given a function $f:X\to Y$, we can send it to:

The function $\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$ sending $S\subseteq X$ to its image $f(S)$. This makes $\mathcal P$ into a covariant functor.
The function $\mathcal P(Y)\to\mathcal P(X)$ sending $T\subseteq Y$ to its preimage $f^{-1}(T)$. This makes $\mathcal P$ into a contravariant functor.

But I've noticed that the contravariant functor appears more often than the covariant one. For instance:

The category $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is equivalent to the category $\mathbf{CABA}$ of complete atomic Boolean algebras. The contravariant equivalence $\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{CABA}$ is the contravariant power set functor.
A function $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous iff the preimage of an open set is open. That is, the result of the contravariant power set functor applied to $f$ preserves openness.

Is there something deeper behind this? Is the contravariant power set functor more "natural" than the covariant power set functor? Or am I trying to find a nonexistent pattern?

Is the fact that I believe this is a great question with no good answer a reason to downvote? ;)

I don't know if this is evidence, but the contravariant power set functor is representable (namely by ${0,1}$), whereas the covariant one is not. But representability alone does not fully explain why the contravariant one is so powerful (pun absolutely intended).

If $f:X\to Y$ then $f^{-1}:\mathcal P(Y)\to \mathcal P(X)$ commutes with all Boolean operations (including infinitary unions and intersections). The "image" map $\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$ commutes with unions but not (in general) with intersections or complements

Counterpoint: The covariant powerset functor is a monad in a fairly natural way (the monad's multiplication $\mathcal{P}^2(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ takes a set of subsets of $X$ to their union), and the Kleisli category for this monad is the category of sets-with-relations-as-morphisms (=:“swram”s). Which means we can see the powerset functor as the composition of two adjoints: the forgetful functor from swrams, and its right adjoint (which on objects takes a swram to the powerset). I think this makes the covariant powerset functor as “natural” as the category of swrams, which I find appealing.

@Gro-Tsen: I don’t read anything here as disputing that the covariant powerset functor is a very natural and useful object.  The suggestion is just that the contravariant version is in some sense even more natural (or natural for more purposes, or something along those lines).

Both your examples of the importance of the contravariant power set functor have a similar nature: They say the contravariant powerset functor can detect morphisms in the category of sets (in the sense of being used to construct an equivalence of categories with the category of sets) and in the category of topological spaces (in the sense of being used to detect whether a morphism of sets is a morphism of topological spaces, though combining the two ideas one can give an equivalence of categories of the category of topological spaces with the category of complete atomic boolean algebras together with a distinguished subset satisfying some axioms).
If we want to apply a functor to detect morphisms in a category, in some sense, we want to compare the functor to the functor $\operatorname{Hom}$. The functor $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ is contravariant in $X$ and covariant in $Y$. The contravariant power set functor is a contravariant homset functor (taking $Y$ to be the two-element set) but the covariant power set functor is not a covariant homset functor.
More precisely, in any concrete category $C$, $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(X,Y)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{Set}}(X,Y)$ such that for any map $W \to X$ the image of $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(X,Y)$  in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{Set}}(W,Y)$ is contained in $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(W,Y)$. You can try to use this to characterize $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(W,X)$ using maps from $X$ to fixed, well-chosen $Y$. If $Y$ has two elements, this can be done using the power set of $X$.
Dually, for any map $Y \to Z$ the image of $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(X,Y)$  in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{Set}}(Z, Z)$ is contained in $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(X,Z)$. You can try to use this to characterize $\operatorname{Hom}_{C}(Y,Z)$ using maps to $Y$ from fixed, well-chosen $X$, but this can't usually be done directly with the power set of $X$ as you need additional data to characterize a map.

$\newcommand{\Sub}{\mathsf{Sub}}
\newcommand{\Set}{\mathsf{Set}}
\newcommand{\Pre}{\mathsf{Pre}}
\newcommand{\P}{\mathcal{P}}$
One factor could be that it is not always obvious when you are dealing with either of these.
For instance, consider categorical logic. It's common to study the fibred preorder $π : \Sub → \Set$ of subsets fibred over sets. For a set $X$, the fiber $\Sub_X$ is essentially the (subset) partial order on $\P(X)$, and the lifting action of arrows $f : X → Y$ corresponds to the contravariant powerset action, which in logic corresponds to substitution.1
Is this the only important powerset functor? No. Often the next thing to study is a left adjoint to substitution. This materializes as, for every $f : X → Y$ an operation $f_! : \Sub_X → \Sub_Y$. This operation is used as the categorical characterization of existential quantification, and it corresponds to the covariant powerset action. $S : \Sub_X$ is mapped to its image in $f$, $\{f(x) : x \in S\}$.2
This setting also suggests you're missing a third (also covariant) powerset functor, corresponding to the right adjoint in the string often written $f_! ⊣ f^* ⊣ f_*$. The middle is substitution, the left is 'existential quantification,' and the right is 'universal quantification.'3 (To my knowledge, the operation has no common name in set theory.)
If you read about categorical logic, though, you probably will not see these specified as being 'powerset functors,' because 1) we're interested in looking at the poset/category structure of $\P(X)$ and 2) these scenarios generalize significantly, and powersets/subobjects are just one special case. But then that means they are both special cases of a pretty widely occurring phenomenon.
As for which thing is 'most natural' here, it is possible to have a logic with substitution but no quantifiers (or just one or the other quantifier), while I think you'd be hard pressed to completely omit substitution. So maybe the contravariant powerset still arises a bit more. However, the analogue of 'the' covariant powerset also shows up a lot there.
I'm uncertain how often this sort of disguised example happens. Certainly something like the adjoint triple $f_! ⊣ f^* ⊣ f_*$ seems to occur frequently, but I don't know what fraction have powersets as special cases.

[1]: Given $S : \Sub_Y$, $\P(f)(S) : \Sub_X$ is the subset of $X$ that corresponds to substituting $f(x)$ for $y$. For the special case $f = π_0 : Γ×X → Γ$, this is the weakening operation.
[2]: The reason this is used for existential quantification is that when $f = π_0 : Γ×X → Γ$, the image is $\{γ \in Γ: ∃x \in X. (γ,x) \in S\}$.
[3]: If $S \in \P(X)$, then $\P_∀(f)(S) = \{y \in Y: ∀ x. f(x) = y → x \in S\}$. If $f = π_0 : Γ × X → Γ$, then this is the set $\{γ \in Γ: ∀x. (γ,x) \in S\}$

Several other good answers have been given, in particular R. van Dobben de Bruyn's remark that the contravariant power set functor, but not the covariant one, is representable.  Something related that may be useful to think about is the idea of duality between algebra and geometry:

In mathematics, one often has an equivalence of categories between algebra-like objects and space-like objects.... Given an algebra-like object A, we assign to it its poset of ideals... which is interpreted as the poset of opens of some space S.... The points of S are ideals corresponding to morphisms A→k, where k is often a particularly simple algebra.... Conversely, given a space-like object S, we assign to it the algebra of morphisms S→k, where k is often the “same” algebra k as above.

For example:

Commutative rings are dual to affine schemes.
Commutative $C^*$-algebras are dual to compact Hausdorff spaces.
Spatial frames are dual to sober topological spaces.
Complete atomic Boolean algebras are dual to sets.

Not all of these have a single dualizing object $k$.  But the last two do, and in both of those cases it is the set $\{0,1\}$ with appropriate structure, and in Set this the representing object for the contravariant power set functor.  This "explains" the two examples you gave in the question, since it means that all four functors involved in these last two dualities are subfunctors of the contravariant power set functor.
